# How to fix "Invalid beam file or no abstract code" error when debugging in Erlang/OTP?

Tags: debugging, erlang

I'm trying to simply use the debugger, however any method given in the docs causes `Monitor > Module > Interpret > *.beam` to return an error: `** Invalid beam file or no abstract code: "/path/z12.beam"`.

The methods to generate debug info I tried are:

1. Linux shell `erlc +debug_info z12.erl`
2. Erlang shell  `> c(z12, [debug_info]).`
3. Directly in the file `compile:file(z12, [debug_info]).`

However none of them seems to work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you cd into the directory containing the file, then launch the erlang shell, then compile with `c(z12).`?  And, what's with `*.beam`?  Choose the module `z12` instead.

Comment: 1. The shell is opened in the file's directory and doesn't work that way.
2. "*.beam" means a filename that ends with ".beam", I was using "z12.beam" as the debug module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you easily load the module using erl shell itself in which debugger was started.

```
c("erl_file_path",[debug_info]).
int:i("path/module_name").
```

example:

```
12> c("/home/badri/hello.erl",[debug_info]). 
{ok,hello} 
15> int:i("/home/badri/hello"). 
{module,hello}
```

Comment: Ok, for some strange reason this method actually works -> ```c(z12, [debug_info]), int:i(z12), debugger:start().``` brings up the monitor with the interpreted module loaded and ready to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting .beam file try with .erl file it would work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Instead, I have to choose the file from the list.   In other words, I can't manually type in a path.   Although, actually typing in a path doesn't cause the op's error--it just doesn't do anything.